# $n \log_2 n$ approximation to $n^x$

Tags: calculus, algorithms, asymptotics

$n \log_2 n$ approximation to $n^x$

I know that $F(n)=n \log_2 n - n^{1.5}<0$ (from $F'(n)<0$). So $ \log_2 n < \sqrt n$

But if $ \log_2 n <n^x$ what could be x which is less than 0.5?

Comment: If I’m understanding correctly, you’re trying to approximate the function $f(n)=n\log_2(n)$ using power functions. In that case, the answer is that $x=1$ is your best solution. Any larger x will cause your power function to increase too fast.

Comment: sir nlogn ~ n? If i keep $n=2^{10} $ , then $2^{10} * 10$ ~ $2^{10}$  Is it the closest approximation or is there any other still close?

Comment: It’s not a great approximation, but as long as you’re searching for something of the form $n^x$ you won’t find anything better. Like you pointed out, x=1.5 grows too fast, and if you have x be anything else bigger than 1, it will grow too fast too, and you get a worse approximation than x=1.

Comment: thank you sir ....